# How to convert longitude and latitude data into shapefiles for NetLogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I have some longitude and latitude data and would like to load them into NetLogo for modeling. I used QGIS to load and visualize the data successfully. Then I exported the data as shapefiles (.shp) format, and there are several other files being exported togeter with postfix .shx, .dbf, .qpj, .prj, and .cpg. 
But when I tried to load the data in NetLogo as

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ elevation ]

to load
  clear-all
  set elevation gis:load-dataset "MyDir/XXX.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of elevation
end
```

it reported an error saying **"Extension exception: only GEOGCS and PROJCS are supported"**

I searched the error online and think maybe it is because the file I exported from QGIS is not supported by NetLogo. But I know nothing about GIS data, so have no idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I compared my .prj file with the example file of NetLogo GIS extension, googled the difference, and found out the solution, which is as followed.

In the QGIS, click **Project** and select **Properties**. There is a **CRS** tag on the left. Open it and one can find a "Coordinate reference systems of the world" window, inside which click the first class named **Geographic Coordinate Systems**, and choose the one named **GCS_WGS_1984_XX**.

[image]

Click **OK** and go back to the main panel. Right click your layer and set the layer's CRS. Choose the **GCS_WGS_1984_XX** one. Now export the layer and it can be loaded by NetLogo successfully.

Comment: If you're able to, you might tell Stackoverflow that you've accepted your answer as the best answer, so it marks the question answered!